# TLP showing different temperatures for different commands

Tags: 16.04, temperature, tlp

I recently installed TLP on my ubuntu system.
On typing `sudo tlp-stat`, the temperature is shown to be 58 degree Celsius, while typing `tlp-stat --temp` gives the temperature value as 51 degrees Celsius.

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: Please check, [edit] and proofread that first command.

Comment: Which temperatures are you referring to it (command output would help)? If its a different rtemp yes its supposed to be different (e.g. SMART hard disk temp). If its `CPU temp` it may just have changed in the time between the commands.

Comment: I was referring to the CPU temperature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using `sudo tlp stat` or `sudo tlp-stat`, it's going to fetch a lot of information about system, to gather this data the CPU usge goes up and thus you get a higher CPU temperature with this command.
 However while you are using `sudo tlp-stat --temp` you are only requesting a single data, in this case tlp itself does not uses that much CPU so  you get a lower temperature.

In a terminal run `watch sudo tlp-stat --temp` in another one run `sudo tlp-stat` and pay attention to the first terminal. While the second command is being run the first one changes and the number will be closed to the second one.

Comment: Yes sir! I observed it. But I wonder does the CPU temperature really shoot up by that amount? The system fetches the information really fast, takes hardly a second. When I ran the second command <code> sudo tlp-stat </code>, the value in the first terminal shot up by 7 degrees.

Comment: Yeah, it's just for a second and temperature will be captured exactly at that moment.

Comment: classic Heisenberg (: